# Take a guess on what I am

Tags: riddle

```
Any fragment has me
yet I am unseen
I depend on another's mass
From the tiniest to the enormous

and if I would ever happen to be ceased
without me all the universe would be fixed
```

Comment: Is it a natural phenomenon by which all things with mass are brought toward (or gravitate toward) one another?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I am going to guess the answer is

> gravity
>
>  not visible
>  based on mass
>  required for orbits

Not sure about the any fragment has me

Comment: But without gravity interstellar objects would also drift apart faster

Comment: @Siddhartha Let's see if it gets the check

Comment: I think the "Any fragment has me" refers to the fact than any piece of matter exerts gravitational force on its surroundings, no matter how large or small that mass is.

Comment: Friendly reminder: We generally put Spoiler tags around answers to avoid revealing the solution to someone who wants to attempt the puzzle on their own.  If commenters then reveal the answer outright in their comments, it defeats the entire purpose. Please don't.

Comment: @Rubio Then I don't understand your comment.

Comment: People are mentioning the answer in the comments to it, making the spoilers on the answer pointless.  But we *want* those spoilers to be useful. We don't want people to spoil the spoilers by giving away the answer in the comments, as people have done here.

Comment: @Rubio OK I think I get it now.

Answer (score 5):

My guess is that you are

> An Electron

Any fragment has me

> Anything can be split into atoms which contain electrons

yet I am unseen

> Can't be seen by the naked eye

I depend on another's mass

> Depend's on a proton which has a mass (Atomic mass for # of protons)

From the tiniest to the enormous

> Small atoms to large ones

and if I would ever happen to be ceased

> Electrons are always moving

without me all the universe would be fixed

> Nothing would change or react without electrons passing between atoms?

Comment: Err... Electrons do have a Mass. I think the OP probably means that mass of electron is 1/1850 times that of proton(hence, the dependence upon another object's mass)

Comment: I didn't mean that they did not have a mass, just that they are drawn to a proton's mass. But yeah, perhaps.

Comment: @PaigeMeinke, they are drawn to a proton's **charge**.

Comment: You right. Well I guess a large charge = large # of protons = large mass

Comment: Friendly reminder: We generally put Spoiler tags around answers to avoid revealing the solution to someone who wants to attempt the puzzle on their own.  If commenters then reveal the answer outright in their comments, it defeats the entire purpose. Please don't.

Comment: @Rubio Vafgrnq, lbh pna [ebg13](http://rot13.com/) lbhe pbzzragf.

Answer (score 3):

I think all of the clues point to the following answer:

> Time

Comment: Usually an answer will include how each stanza fits your answer.

Comment: @Ben  I was about to provide this answer with the appropriate additional explanations relative to the question.  Then I saw your answer and decided to suggest that you edit your answer to be more complete.  I do believe that your answer is the correct one...just incomplete

Comment: how does that depend on mass?

Comment: @AsheKetchum `A clock that is under the influence of a stronger gravitational field than an observer's will also be measured to tick slower than the observer's own clock.` [Time dilation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_dilation)

Comment: That would not mean the actual time is going slower, it is just the mechanism of the clock ticking slower.

Answer (score 2):

you are

> Gravitational Waves

Any fragment has me

> Every object that has mass, creates gravitational waves

yet I am unseen

> Gravitational waves cannot be seen

I depend on another's mass

> Gravitational waves only take effect when there is another object with mass that the waves can act upon

From the tiniest to the enormous

> Again, all objects with mass generate gravitational waves

and if I would ever happen to be ceased
without me all the universe would be fixed

> gravitational waves create the movements in space. Without them, there would be no 'outside' force to generate motion.

Comment: What you refer to is in their most basic sense, ripples in space-time.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may be

> An orbit

Any fragment has me yet I am unseen

> Fragment to me sounds like it is refering to physical matter. Used in this context all fragments have orbiting electrons. Generally you cannot have matter without orbiting electrons. Also the orbital path itself cannot be seen with the naked eye.

I depend on another's mass

> Electron orbits are dependant upon the mass of the nucleous in order for them to orbit.

From the tiniest to the enormous

> The smallest objects like atoms to the biggest objects like planets and stars can have orbits.

and if I would ever happen to be ceased without me all the universe would be fixed

> I am no physicist but I believe if orbits were to cease its possible matter itself could be fixed, or for lack of a better term standing still (If it even existed for that matter...).

As I said before

> I am no physicist so some of the atomic decriptions I gave may not be 100% accurate.

Answer (score 0):

You are

> SpaceTime

Because every fragment will take up at least some.

It is definitely not view-able.

It is defined by the masses around it.
(tiny and enormous)

If it ends, the universe ends.

Answer (score 0):

It could be

> Energy OR Attraction

Any fragment has me

> everything consists energy as well everything attracts towards something

yet I am unseen

> we cant see energy and attraction

I depend on another's mass

> Mass is actually a transformation of energy into elemental particles & then atoms and also the Amount of attraction/force depends on mass

From the tiniest to the enormous

> small and large everything has both!

and if I would ever happen to be ceased
without me all the universe would be fixed

> without energy/Attraction all universe would be fixed

Answer (score 0):

Is it

> GOD

Any fragment has me

> god exists in everything .

yet I am unseen

> we can't see god.

I depend on another's mass
From the tiniest to the enormous

> God exists if we think GOD exists ..else GOD doesn't exist.

and if I would ever happen to be ceased
without me all the universe would be fixed

> This universe is run by GOD